# If I have two convex functions . I want to prove sup is convex?

Tags: real-analysis

If I have two convex functions . I want to prove sup is convex ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the epigraph of $x \mapsto \max(f(x),g(x))$ is the intersection of
the epigraphs of $f,g$.

The intersection of two convex sets is convex, and a function is convex **iff**
its epigraph is convex.